# Use a result of variable as a name for another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create a variable name based on id value of another variable. I thought this would work.

So when I click one of the 4 tables, I obtain the tables id.
Example: 676.

I am then trying to create a variable using such number

```
var id = 66;
var 'table' + id = ''; // expecting var table66 = '';
```

I get error above.
but if I try

var table66 = '';

it works
No matter how I try adding "cans" + "66" equal to a new selector variable it will not work.

I am trying to achieve getting the id and a string. add them together to create a new variable name

Comment: This very much sounds like you're trying to solve problem A by doing B, when doing C would be a much better way of doing it.

Comment: You probably should be using an array, not separate variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object and use the variables as object properties. This will allow you to scope within a function and not pollute global window.

```
var id = 66;
var obj={};
obj['table' + id] = 'test';
alert(obj.table66); //"test"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window object as an object and use bracket notation:
[image]

```
id = 66;
window['table' + id] = 'test';
alert(table66); //"test"
```

Comment: This has the problem of basically creating global variables rather than something scoped to the function.